# how to configure the fluentd daemonset syslog and forward everything?

Tags: fluentd, syslog

Im trying to use this one, https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/fluentd-daemonset-syslog.yaml
Configured the syslog host, IP, protocol, applied it and only not so useful logs appear at my remote rsyslog server ( I mean it was not from any app or system pod logs, just this

```
Apr 15 15:42:05 fluentd-xzdgs fluentd: _BOOT_ID:cfd4dc3fdedb496c808df2fd8adeb9ac#011_MACHINE_ID:eXXXXXXXXXXbc28e1#011_HOSTNAME:ip-11.22.33.444.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal#011PRIORITY:6#011_UID:0#011_GID:0#011_CAP_EFFECTIVE:3fffffffff#011_SYSTEMD_SLICE:system.slice#011_TRANSPORT:stdout#011SYSLOG_FACILITY:3#011_STREAM_ID:03985e96bd7c458cbefaf81c6f866297#011SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER:kubelet#011_PID:3424#011_COMM:kubelet#011_EXE:/usr/bin/kubelet#011_CMDLINE:/usr/bin/kubelet --cloud-provider aws --config /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json --kubeconfig /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig --container-runtime remote --container-runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock --network-plugin cni --node-ip=111.222.333.444 --pod-infra-container-image=602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/eks/pause:3.1-eksbuild.1 --v=2 --node-labels=eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-04e2f0450bc3d0837,eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND,eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=XXXXX-20220401043
```

I did not configure anythings else.
My k8s version is 1.21 EKS
Checked the fluentd ds pod, it started slowly from pattern not match to a complete loop with "\\\" a few sec laters.

the fluentd pod logs :

```
2022-04-15 15:48:43 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: "2022-04-15T15:48:42.671721363Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:42 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \"2022-04-15T15:48:41.634512612Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:41 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\"2022-04-15T15:48:40.596571231Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:40 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\\\\\"2022-04-15T15:48:39.617967459Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:39 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-04-15T15:48:38.628577821Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:38 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-04-15T15:48:37.612301989Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:37 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-04-15T15:48:36.569418367Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:36 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-04-15T15:48:35.562340916Z stdout F 2022-04-15 15:48:35 +0000 [info]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] following tail of /var/log/containers/podname-kr8mg_namespacename-ecc1e41b47da5ae6b34fd372475baf34e129540af59a3455f29541d6093eedb7.log\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
```

How do i forward everythings in my application logs? my k8s app's logs are not json and with just multiline or single line logs with no structure or any formats.

Many Thanks!.

Comment: Please share the function you use to create log messages, as well as the configuration file you're currently using.

Comment: hey thanks @eDonkey , I have figured out, the default configuration on fluentd is dockerd, the newest k8s run with containerd, so I have to changed the parser type the cri.
problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out, the default configuration on fluentd is dockerd, the newest k8s run with containerd, so I have to changed the parser type the cri. problem solved!